# Can we say anything about $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)$ if $p\nmid x-y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

I know about the LTE lemma which says the following: If $p$ is a prime and $x,y,n$ are natural numbers with $p\nmid xy$ and $p\mid x-y$, then
$$ \nu_p(x^n-y^n)=\nu_p(x-y)+\nu_p(n),$$
where $\nu_p(n)$ is the multiplicity of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $n$.

I was wondering if we can make any statements about $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)$ if the conditions of the lemma do not hold; it is quite easy to reduce the case $p\mid xy$ to the case $p\nmid xy$, but I cannot immediately see how to make any statements about $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)$ in the case where $p\nmid xy$ and $p\nmid x-y$.

Can anyone offer any useful conclusions concerning $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)$ in this particular case or is it impossible to make any general statements here?

Comment: Since $x^n-y^n\equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$ if and only if $(xy^{-1})^n \equiv 1\pmod{p^k}$, this is really a question about the order of $xy^{-1}$ modulo $p^k$ for various values of $k$. In general the answer can be any divisor of $\phi(p^k)$.

Answer (score 2):

(LTE in the form you stated it requires that $p$ be odd.)

As Greg Martin says in the comments, if $p \nmid xy$ then $p \mid x^n - y^n$ iff $\left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^n \equiv 1 \bmod p$. The set of $n$ for which this occurs consists of multiples of the order of $\frac{x}{y} \bmod p$, which can be any divisor of $p - 1$. If we write $d$ for the order, then information about $\nu_p(x^n - y^n)$ for $d \mid n$ can be obtained by applying LTE to $x' = x^d, y' = y^d$. The conclusion is that if $d \mid n$ (and $p$ is odd) then

$$\nu_p(x^n - y^n) = \nu_p(x^d - y^d) + \nu_p \left( \frac{n}{d} \right)$$

and if $d \nmid n$ then $\nu_p(x^n - y^n) = 0$.